# Getting Error "You cannot commit during a managed transaction"|"You cannot rollback during a subordinate session"

Tags: hibernate, spring-transactions, jta

I am using `<xa-datasource>` configuration in my jboss-eap standalone.

Inside my resourceDaoImpl ,I am doing query.executeUpdate() to execute the HSQL query.
But I am getting error like `"You cannot commit during a managed transaction"|"You cannot rollback during a subordinate session"`.

I tried many options

1. Using `@TransactionManagement(value=TransactionManagementType.BEAN)` to keep the transaction at bean level.But still getting error.
2. Instead of `<xa-datasource>` use `<datasource jta="true"...>`,But still same error.

I am not getting any clue.

**EDIT:**

The call stack is very simple,I am using spring hibernate as a framework.
getting the XA datasource connection and executing the storedprocedure using JPA query.

Inside the stored procedure I am using

```
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
```

and `COMMIT;`

**EDIT[1]:**

```
@Repository
public class MyBatchDaoImpl implements MyBatchDao {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    void runMyBatch() {
        StringBuilder query =null;
        dataSource = getMydataSource();   //this method does the jndi lookup for my datasource
        
        query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("call my_sp()");
        CallableStatement st    =   dataSource.getConnection().prepareCall(query.toString());
    
        st.execute();
        st.closeStatement();
    }
}
```

The interface called:

```
public interface  MyBatchDao{

   void runMyBatch();
}
```

This is the gist of my code.

Comment: How is this related to spring? You are using an EJB annotation that isn't supported by Spring but still it is marked as Spring. So either show us what is spring related or please remove those tags.

Comment: It seems the container started a managed transaction prior to the call of your dao and your dao is calling commit when it is not supposed to. Please post a basic, but fully working, example of your code including the call stack (and nature of it), so we can assess the real origin of your problem.

Comment: @PauloAraújo: I am using commit inside the stored procedure,Calling the stored procedure from data access layer.Also I am using PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION inside my stored procedure.

Comment: @Shadab , I don't have a proper oracle installation here to test your scenario, but the call to a procedure in PL/SQL using autonomous_transaction should not trigger any commit on transaction. Can you, as I asked last time, post a almost fully working code including the call stack (EJBs, CDI and transaction demarcations)?

Comment: Using Oracle XE 18 and Payara 5.2020.3, I tested your described scenario using CDI and JPA, bud didn't get any errors. The stored autonomous_transaction procedure worked perfectly both when the main container managed transaction is commited and rollbacked. I've used both xa and non-xa datasources in my tests. Your problem must be about some erroneous transaction definition in you code. If you post it here, we may actually help. Probably, as @M.Deinum refered, the problem emerges from the mix between EJB and Spring.

Comment: @PauloAraújo: Thanks! I am also looking out to maintain a consistency in my code,and remove EJB interference as much as possible.I have updated the gist of my code.Hope it helps.

Comment: @shadab, did your changes fixed the issue?

Comment: @PauloAraújo: Yes,I was able to fix the issue.I made everything as resource local JTA transaction.